# WAMPSERVER Offline

Tags: html, apache, netbeans, wamp, wampserver

I am having trouble connecting WAMPSERVER.
I am using a network which requires proxy and port to work, so basically I'm having trouble when ever I execute my html project it shows me an error

*Not Found
The requested URL /www/index.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80*

I think I have to set proxy setting for my WAMPSERVER.
Can anyone help me with that!

Comment: Nowhere near enough infomation to enable anything other than guesses. Please add more detail.

Comment: The error message is a message from Apache. That means that the webserver itself is up and running, and it's probably not proxy settings. The message basically sais that index.html is not found. Do you have an index.html in the right directory?

Comment: Check the Image in the link may be it will help you understand what I am trying to ask....
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8j6y0jttgf76lom/Screenshot%20%289%29.png?dl=0

Comment: I understand the question, but your interpretation of the error is wrong. WampServer is not offline and was found. But now it is looking for `www/index.html` and this file doesn't exist. Possibly, `www` is your document root folder, and you should leave it out of the url, so the url becomes: http://localhost/index.html

Comment: @GolezTrol yes it is in my (C:\wamp\www\index.html) directory.

Comment: Exactly. `C:\wamp\www` is probably the document root folder. So the url you used is wrong. Have you tried mine from the comment above?

Comment: but it is in that directory wwww/index.html and it works fine when I open the file from the directory. But when I execute it from net-beans it shows the error: The requested URL /www/index.html was not found on this server.

Comment: Yes I tried and it works :)
how can I change my url using net-beans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation of WAMP is (usually) in `C:\Wamp`. But the document root is in `C:\Wamp\www`.

The document root is the starting folder of your url. So the url `http://localhost/foo/bar.html` loads the file in `C:\Wamp\www\foo\bar.html`.

So in conclusion, your url is wrong. It should not be `localhost/www/index.html`, but `localhost/index.html` (without www).

In Netbeans, you can run your project, which basically means that it opens the main page in a browser. If the url you get from Netbeans is wrong, you'll have to change your project settings.

The issue starts when you create a new project in Netbeans. When you point it to `C:\Wamp\www`, netbeans assumes for some reason that `www` should be part of the url. You can change it right away in this project wizard:

[image]

If you forgot to do this, you can do it later. Open the project properties windows (Right-click -> Properties), and choose the tab 'Run configuration'. There you can change the setting:

[image]

Comment: Added some Netbeans screenshots. You were fooled by the default behaviour of the Netbeans new project wizard. :)

Comment: Yup I was :P Thanks (y)